# Android Large PNG not showing issue

Tags: android, png, large-files

This is an issue that I have just come across.

I was using a png that was 3000 px h and 1 px wide then squashing down and stretching wide in the xml.
On the xml layout designer view in eclipse it is shown fine,
however on device it does not.

This is weird!

Comment: Why would you need an image 3000px wide, no devices are anywhere near that wide!

Comment: @ToddDavies Well, there is Google TV.

Comment: Well said, however he says 'device' which suggests he's not working with Google TV...

Comment: @RaghavSood no matter the display size, a 3000x1 image is probably gradient or one color, so no need to use a png for that...

Comment: I know. I was just saying that devices can exist with such displays, not saying that he should be doing it.

Comment: @WarrenFaith it is a complex gradient, to complex to draw programatically.

Comment: also yes 3000, was a bit of an exageration it was actually 2450. The reason it is this big was so that we can cover any device with any density without stretching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why but it seems that there is a max image height of 2000px in the android compiler/renderer or something? My fix was to make the image at 2000px height.

Comment: I have to add that it changes from device to device and from one android version to another.